# How integral of 0 is C???

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Toady I read that integral of 0 is C. because integral = antiderivative.

How can this be true, because we know that an **integral is
the area under a curve**...and there is no area under the line x = 0,
then how its area will be any Constant(after integrating the curve)

Answer (score 2):

Fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=F(b)-F(a)$$

For your case:

$$\int_a^b0\ dx=C-C=0$$

Comment: what if there are no a and b. i mean no limits or boundings for a general solution

Comment: @TauqeerHassan Then it does not represent area under a curve.

Comment: can u differentiate me between definti and indefinte integrals and what type of integral will be in this question

Comment: @TauqeerHassan Please see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109225/whats-the-connection-between-the-indefinite-integral-and-the-definite-integral

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing definite and indefinite integrals.

A *definite* integral $\int_a^b \cdots dx$ can (under some common conditions) be interpreted as the area under a curve, but an *indefinite* integral $\int \cdots dx$ cannot -- it's not even a number but a function (well, a family of functions) *defined* simply by the requirement that its derivative must be the integrand.