# What is the relationship between integrals and areas?

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the area under a curve the integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15294/why-is-the-area-under-a-curve-the-integral)

Why does calculating an integral or an anti-derivatives represent an area? How do they figure it out? What is the relationship between them?

Comment: A textbook on calculus will have some explanation and intuitive motivation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic level stuff covered in first course of calculus. You may also refer to this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Geometric_intuition