# How does integration work algebraically?

Tags: calculus, integration

Based on [Why do differentiating and integrating 'work'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312831/why-do-differentiating-and-integrating-work)

In differentiation, you take the gradient of a point $x$ by differentiating. To this, you take two points on the graph, one which is the point where you want to find the gradient of, and another one (which is explained later).

[image: Differentiation]

As you can see, there are two points:

$$(a,f(a)) \text{ and } (a+h,f(a+h))$$

Where $h$ is the distance between the points.

We take the gradient of these two points, and we get:

$$f'(x)=\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{(a+h)-a}$$

$$=\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

To find the gradient of a point, we take $h$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ which gives us the gradient of the graph at $x$

---

So, now about integration.

[image: integration]

I understand that integration is using a trapezium rule to take the limit as the width of each strip $\rightarrow 0$ and the number of strips $\rightarrow \infty$

This gives us
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x_i$$

$n=$ number of strips

$\Delta x_i =$ width of strip $i$

So what is the algebraic reasoning behind this transformation of a function?

All images belong to [Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/313135/402319)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "algebraic reasoning"?

Comment: @leibnewtz $$f'(x)=\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{(a+h)-a}=\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$ The integrating equivalent

Comment: The direct equivalent is just the definition of the Riemann sum. The *geometric* equivalent is that you approximate the area under the curve by the area of a bunch of rectangles that lie under (or mostly under) the curve. As you make the rectangles narrower, the white space and "black space" (i.e. rectangle area *above* the curve) get smaller. Thus for the derivative, you approximate the slope at a point using the slope of a line between two points that are actually on the given curve. For the integral, you approximate the area as the area under a "curve" close to the given curve.

Comment: This is a pretty good summary of calculus, but it's not clear what you are asking.  Are you wanting an algebraic motivation that's completely divorced from geometry?

Comment: @VortexYT Why should the two ideas be defined similarly? One is the limit of a function, the other is the limit of a sequence. That the two are connected by the fundamental theorem of calculus is pretty amazing

Comment: If you want to really understand the link between differentiation and integration, it is best that you have a look at the proof of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. For me a proof is only thing that explains the mystery. Any other tactics only reduce the mystery somewhat and sometimes lead to the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, but this is how I like to think about integration. [image]

Consider a small change of the area under $f(x)$, this is $dA$. Since $dA$ is small, the red part (change in area) approaches roughly $f(x)dx$ (area of rectangle), so $dA=f(x)dx$, or $$\frac{dA}{dx}=f(x)$$

This means that $A(x)$ is the anti-derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: It'd be nice to show the rectangle of height $f(x)$ and width $dx$ in the picture, so the error for finite $dx$ is clearer.

Comment: @Ian You're right, I'll update the picture. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can estimate differentiation by taking the two points $f(x)$ and $f(x+h)$ like you said, and then shrinking $h$. What algebraic differentiation does is reduces the $h$ to an extremely small quantity, and outputs the gradient between two points that are virtually the same but only just not.

With the Trapezium Rule for Integration Approximation, you have a class width ($h$ or $w$). As your h shrinks, the values get closer. Again, all algebraic integration does is shrink your h to an extremely small quantity and gives you the area there, which due to the tiny class width, is accurate to the curve.