# Definite integral and the antiderviative in relation to area under a curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Part of my paper is asking me to conceptualize how the definite integral is used to find the area under a curve and show the relation to the antiderivative. I do well at the beginning, but I always end up lost(I think because I'm not very good at connecting the two). I said that the area can be found by making lots of rectangles under a curve, and the more rectangles, the more accurate your area. And if we have change in x approaching 0, we can solve for actual area. This is represented by the Riemann Sum. Is this the definite integral? So far I just have that the definite integral is the area under a curve between two points, a and b.and what part does A= Sum f(x)dx play? Is that the anti derivative? We got assigned this before we've really covered alot of this, so consider me a newbie(very, very new)

Comment: The definite integral is just the Riemann sum in the limit as the norm of your chosen partition goes to $0$ (assuming said sum exists) -- basically the limit as each of your $\Delta x_i$'s go to $0$.  The relation to the antiderivative is the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) -- to really get a hold on that I'd suggest going through the proof.

Comment: And... For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: so would it be accurate to say that the Riemann sum is the sum of the products(rectangles) and the definite integral is the Riemann sum as the change in x approaches 0(as the base of the rectangles approaches 0)?

Comment: That's basically it.  There can be some slight complications -- for instance functions can be made up whose upper and lower Riemann sums don't converge to the same limit -- in which case the function is said to NOT be integrable.  But you've got the basic idea down.

Comment: Yes! and thanks for the links. My teacher gave us that the equation and function for the area are related by the antiderivative. I tried looking around and I think I could get by but I really want to understand it. When i was looking around, I saw the A= Sum f(x)dx and that if you take the antiderivative of f, you get A. I'm just stuck on connecting the definite integral with that idea (if it's right)

Comment: Is it that the definite integral as the limit of a riemann sum is found by taking the anti derivative of f?

Comment: $\sum_i^n f(x_i)\Delta x_i$ IS the Riemann sum.  The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that if we have $\int_a^b f'(x)dx$ then this is the same as $f(b)-f(a)$ -- subject to some conditions.  $f(x)$ is called the "antiderivative" of $f'(x)$.  It is just the *class* of functions, all of whose derivative is $f'(x)$.  For example, looking at $\int_0^1 e^{2x}dx$.  We know that any function of the form $\dfrac {e^{2x}}{2} + C$, where $C$ is a constant, will have a derivative of $e^{2x}$.  So the FTC tells us that $\int_0^1 e^{2x}dx = (\dfrac {e^{2(1)}}{2} + C) - (\dfrac {e^{2(0)}}{2} + C)$

Comment: ... $=\dfrac {e^2}{2} - \dfrac 12$.  That's a big help because this way, no Riemann sums have to be calculated.

Comment: If you'd like more info, check out [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15294/why-is-the-area-under-a-curve-the-integral?rq=1).  The first answer is really good.