# why is integration the area under a curve

Tags: calculus

Why is integration the area under a curve (graphically)?
Derivative gives the slope which makes perfect sense as it shows the change at a point. But how is, its opposite, the integral represented by the area under the curve.

Comment: What definition of integration are you using? It's quite clear from the Riemann sums definition.

Comment: If you're looking for reasoning that the Anti-Derivative finds the area under a curve, there is some good discussion and graphics on this question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15294/why-is-the-area-under-a-curve-the-integral

Answer (score 2):

The integral as a limit of Riemann sums DEFINES the area under a curve. You can COMPUTE the integral by computing the anti derivative and applying the fundamental theorem of calculus. But the integral is the definition of area.